# JTable with different JCombobox for each line

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have a table that I'm loading with rows at run time.  Once loaded the user needs to choose an item from a `JComboBox` in the first column for each line.  Then he needs to chose an item from another `JComboBox`on the same line in every rows.  The content of the second `JComboBox` depends on the selection of the first `JComboBox`.

The way I coded it now is changing the combobox content for the whole second column.

```
columnProfile.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBoxProf))
```

Is there a way to have a combobox object different on every row so I can work on it everytime I select a value in the first combobox?

The number of rows is not fixed until the user hits submit.  He can add and delete rows.

I've used the basic Table example from Oracle and made the changes to reflect what I'm currently doing

```
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;


import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;


public class TableRenderDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;
    JComboBox comboBox2;
    JComboBox comboBox1;
    public TableRenderDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        initColumnSizes(table);

        setUpSportColumn(table, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2));
        setUpYearsColumn(table, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3));

        add(scrollPane);
        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

                if (e.getColumn() == 2){
                    comboBox2.removeAllItems();
                    /*REFILL COMBOBOX WITH WHAT I NEED FOR THIS ROW ONLY*/
                }


            }
                  }); 
    }

    private void initColumnSizes(JTable table) {
        MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel)table.getModel();
        TableColumn column = null;
        Component comp = null;
        int headerWidth = 0;
        int cellWidth = 0;
        Object[] longValues = model.longValues;
        TableCellRenderer headerRenderer =
            table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);

            comp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                                 null, column.getHeaderValue(),
                                 false, false, 0, 0);
            headerWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

            comp = table.getDefaultRenderer(model.getColumnClass(i)).
                             getTableCellRendererComponent(
                                 table, longValues[i],
                                 false, false, 0, i);
            cellWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Initializing width of column "
                                   + i + ". "
                                   + "headerWidth = " + headerWidth
                                   + "; cellWidth = " + cellWidth);
            }

            column.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(headerWidth, cellWidth));
        }
    }

    public void setUpSportColumn(JTable table,
                                 TableColumn sportColumn) {
        //Set up the editor for the sport cells.
        comboBox1 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox1.addItem("Snowboarding");
        comboBox1.addItem("Rowing");
        comboBox1.addItem("Knitting");
        comboBox1.addItem("Speed reading");
        comboBox1.addItem("Pool");
        comboBox1.addItem("None of the above");
        sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox1));


        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =
                new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
        sportColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    }
    public void setUpYearsColumn(JTable table,
            TableColumn yearColumn) {

comboBox2 = new JComboBox();
comboBox2.addItem("1");
comboBox2.addItem("2");
comboBox2.addItem("3");
comboBox2.addItem("4");
comboBox2.addItem("5");
comboBox2.addItem("6");
yearColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox2));

//Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =
new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
yearColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
}

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                        "Last Name",
                                        "Sport",
                                        "# of Years",
                                        "Vegetarian"};
        private Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
         "Snowboarding", "1", new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
         "Rowing", "1", new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black",
         "Knitting", "1", new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White",
         "Speed reading", "1", new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown",
         "Pool", "1", new Boolean(false)}
        };

        public final Object[] longValues = {"Jane", "Kathy",
                                            "None of the above",
                                            new Integer(20), Boolean.TRUE};

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }


        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }


        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {

            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }


        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                                   + " to " + value
                                   + " (an instance of "
                                   + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();

            for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRenderDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        TableRenderDemo newContentPane = new TableRenderDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); 
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your best attempt at a [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org) where you condense your code into the smallest bit, small enough to post with your question as code-formatted text, that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. This will make it much easier for folks to answer your question and help you solve your problem.

Comment: One solution is to have your cell editor *extend* the DefaultCellEditor, override the `getTableCellEditorComponent(...)`, and change the model of the JComboBox that this editor holds. For more details, again please show us your [mcve].

Comment: I have added the code.  Thanks!

Comment: Your *own* code please, one that shows your attempt to use the two comboboxes.

Comment: You can see it there, I have combobox1 and combobox2.  You can run this code.  I'm just not comfortable sharing my whole code since my work would not like it.  But what is there represents what I would like to do.  Look at line /*REFILL COMBOBOX WITH WHAT I NEED FOR THIS ROW ONLY*/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you had your data held in a `Map<String, List<String>>` with the Map's keys representing the values held by the first JComboBox, and the Map's values representing the changing values held by the 2nd column's JComboBox (the data does not need to be set up this way, but it's easy for MCVE/demonstration purposes), and call this map `dataMap`, then your column editor could look something like:

```
    column1.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo1) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

            // the items that will fill our JComboBox. Initially its empty
            Object[] items = new Object[]{};

            // get the value in the column to the left
            Object column0Value = table.getValueAt(row, column - 1);
            if (column0Value != null) {
                // if the value is not null, then get the map's values
                // and use it to fill our items array
                items = dataMap.get(column0Value).toArray();
            } 

            // get the super component, the JComboBox that is being used
            // as an editor:
            JComboBox<Object> superCombo = (JComboBox<Object>) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                    row, column);

            // create a model and fill with items
            DefaultComboBoxModel<Object> comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(items);

            // set the cell editor's model and return
            superCombo.setModel(comboModel);
            return superCombo;
        }
    });
```

For example please check this MCVE as an example that uses the above cell editor and as an example of a MCVE that would work well in your future questions

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TableWithMultCombos extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = { "Day of Week", "Number" };
    private Map<String, List<String>> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private DefaultTableModel tblModel = new DefaultTableModel(COLUMN_NAMES, 5);
    private JTable table = new JTable(tblModel);
    private DefaultComboBoxModel<Object> combo2Model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    private JComboBox<Object> combo0 = null;
    private JComboBox<Object> combo1 = new JComboBox<>(combo2Model);

    public TableWithMultCombos() {
        dataMap.put("Monday", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Mon - 1", "Mon - 2", "Mon - 3", "Mon - 4" }));
        dataMap.put("Tuesday", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Tues - 1", "Tues - 2", "Tues - 3", "Tues - 4" }));
        dataMap.put("Wednesday", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Wed - 1", "Wed - 2", "Wed - 3", "Wed - 4" }));
        dataMap.put("Thursday", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Thurs - 1", "Thurs - 2", "Thurs - 3", "Thurs - 4" }));
        dataMap.put("Friday", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Fri - 1", "Fri - 2", "Fri - 3", "Fri - 4" }));
        combo0 = new JComboBox<>(dataMap.keySet().toArray());

        TableColumn column0 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        column0.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo0));

        TableColumn column1 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        column1.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo1) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                    boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

                // the items that will fill our JComboBox. Initially its empty
                Object[] items = new Object[]{};

                // get the value in the column to the left
                Object column0Value = table.getValueAt(row, column - 1);
                if (column0Value != null) {
                    // if the value is not null, then get the map's values
                    // and use it to fill our items array
                    items = dataMap.get(column0Value).toArray();
                } 

                // get the super component, the JComboBox that is being used
                // as an editor:
                JComboBox<Object> superCombo = (JComboBox<Object>) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                        row, column);

                // create a model and fill with items
                DefaultComboBoxModel<Object> comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(items);

                // set the cell editor's model and return
                superCombo.setModel(comboModel);
                return superCombo;
            }
        });

        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TableWithMultCombos mainPanel = new TableWithMultCombos();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableWithMultCombos");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to run this code and now understand what I need to do.  This is really appreciated